# How to achieve the functionality described below

Tags: go, go-interface

I need to do something like this:

```
// I have an interface with these two methods defined
type mapper interface {
    ReadMapper(interface{}) interface{}
    WriteMapper(interface{}) interface{}
}
```

then I need to assign `ReadMapper` and `WriteMapper` some functions which are defined somewhere else in the project. Is there is a way to do something like this in Go? Assigning functions to them?

```
   V1Mapper mapper
   V1Mapper.ReadMapper = functions()....
   V1Mapper.WriteMapper = functions()....
```

Then, I need another map and want the mapper as the value type and want to do something like below.

```
mappingFunctions := map[string]mapper

mappingFunctions ["some_string"] = V1Mapper
```

and then from another file, I want to do this:

```
mappingFunctions["some_string"].ReadMapper(Data)
```

EDIT: I never asked for syntax in the question. I just wanted to know if there was a better way to do this because I was new to Go. I do agree I am not very much familiar with the syntax of the Go and I will have to go through the documentation (not once but many times).

Comment: How about using a struct with functions instead of interface?

Comment: I just looked on the internet what u suggested (about using struct). Do u mean something like this???  
`type mapper struct {
 ReadMapper   func(interface{}) interface{}
 WriteMapper   func(interface{}) interface{}
}`

Comment: will this allow me to use dot notation to assign functions as values?

Comment: Please read through [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1). It will take about 15 minutes, and should any basic syntax question like this. If you still have specific questions after that, let us know.

Comment: @rayan yes, something like that. That struct would not implement any interface, but you can still can call the function and assign them.

Comment: People, this question is not about syntax. It's about design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compose mappers from the existing functions, you can use structures instead of interfaces:

```
type Mapper struct {
    ReadMapper  func(interface{}) interface{}
    WriteMapper func(interface{}) interface{}
}

mappers := map[string]*Mapper{}
mappers["some_name"] = &Mapper{
    ReadMapper: someFunc1,
    WriteMapper: someFunc2,
}
```

or

```
m := new(Mapper)
m.ReadMapper = someFunc1
m.WriteMapper = someFunc2
mappers["some_name"] = m
```